# Python, counting from an inputted string. Needs to be returned in a specific order?

Tags: python

So i am typing a code where a user will need to input >>Count('bla bla bla') and the program needs to count the in the bla bla bla phrase and return the word with its count in this SPECIFIC order.

Any Help?

Comment: You're counting how many times each vowel appears *in `vowels`*. That's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `count` function is not used correctly. You want `text.search(vowel)`, not `vowel.search(text)`

```
>>> s = 'this is some string with a lot of vowels'
>>> vowels = 'aeiou'
>>> {i : s.count(i) for i in vowels}
{'a': 1, 'i': 4, 'e': 2, 'u': 0, 'o': 4}
```

Dictionaries have no order, so if you want the count in vowel order:

```
>>> [(i,s.count(i)) for i in vowels]
[('a', 1), ('e', 2), ('i', 4), ('o', 4), ('u', 0)]
```

Comment: or, to keep order, use an `OrderedDict`

Answer (score 1):

```
def vowelCount(text):
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    return ("a, e, i, o, and u appear, respectively, %s times." %", ".join([ str(text.count(x)) for x in vowels]))

print vowelCount('bla bla bla')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, what about the display in that specific order?

Comment: You'll need this: returned_value = vowelCount("bla bla bla")

Comment: I was assuming you know python. Check out the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo:

```
def vowelCount(text):
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    counts = {x:text.count(x) for x in vowels}
    keys = counts.keys()
    values = counts.values()
    return ','.join(keys[:-1]) + ' and '+ keys[-1] +' appear, respectively, '+ ','.join(str(v) for v in values)+' times.'
```

Answer (score 0):

The code as written doesn't even examine the input text at all. You're counting the number of times each vowel appears in `vowels`.

Replace with `text.count(i)` instead of `vowels.count(i)`.

Comment: Well, now you have a dictionary of vowel:count pairs. So just write a format string:

    `"a, e, i, o, and u appear, respectively, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d times" % (counts['a'], counts['e'], counts['i'], counts['o'], counts['u'])`

There's probably a prettier way of doing it, but this works fine.

Comment: Well, that code as written doesn't do any formatting. Adding `.format(**counts)` at the end would do the trick, if you've put the return value of the function into the variable `counts`.